# Silverlight transparent layer

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, behavior, mousemove

I'm using a transparent layer with order to be on top of the other elements to catch a behavior of mouse movements.

The problem is under this layer I have other control I can't catch any click or behavior because it's isolating them from being touch. at the same time I can't change this layer order to be behind cause it's controlling all the other elements movements.

is there anyway to keep this layer a reference for mousemove behavior and at the same time I can touch the elements behind.

Comment: Can you share some code that displays your problem so we can visualize a little better? The way you're describing it goes against logic but it sounds like a fun exercise to figure out.

Comment: You have an element that must be on top of everything, but you don't want it on top of everything? Sounds like a catch-22. Maybe you can have it over everything except these buttons or you can create multiple transparent layers to cover the areas you want to catch the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

MouseMove events on Silverlight automatically bubble up to the parent. You only need to attach a MouseMove listener to the RootVisual. see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousemove(v=vs.95).aspx)

Here's a sample UserControl that you can drop on your MainPage surface and observe mouse move events.

```
<UserControl x:Class="DelmeSlCom.MouseMoveWatcher"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="X" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="Y" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and the relevant code behind

```
public partial class MouseMoveWatcher : UserControl
{
    public MouseMoveWatcher()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (App.Current.RootVisual as MainPage).MouseMove += MouseMoveWatcher_MouseMove;
    }

    void MouseMoveWatcher_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var position = e.GetPosition(App.Current.RootVisual);
        this.X.Text = String.Format("{0:f}", position.X);
        this.Y.Text = String.Format("{0:f}", position.Y);
    }
}
```